# Invariance of continuity equation for Galilei transformations

Tags: conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, notation, galilean-relativity

I want to prove that the continuity equation for fluids, $$\dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\rho \textbf{u}) = 0$$ is invariant by Galilei transformations. My attempt:

Using index notation, the transformation is:

$$ \begin{cases}
x^{i'} = R_j^{i'} x^j - v^{i'} t - d^{i'} \\
t' = t   + \tau,
\end{cases} $$
Where $R$ is an ortogonal matrix, such that $R_i^j R_i^k = \delta_{jk}$.

The needed parcial derivatives in $t$ and $x^i$ of their tranformations are easy to calculate:

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} = R_j ^{i'} \dfrac {\partial x^j}{\partial t} - v^{i'}\\
\dfrac {\partial t'}{\partial t} = 1 \\
\dfrac {\partial x^{i'} }{\partial x^i} = R_i ^{i'} \\
\dfrac {\partial t' }{\partial x^i} = 0
 \end{cases}  $$

From the first of these equations follows that $u^{i'} = R_j ^{i'} u^j - v^{i'}$, since it is a velocity field.

Then, I can write the derivatives:
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac {\partial }{\partial t} = \dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t } \dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^{i'} } + \dfrac {\partial t' }{\partial t} \dfrac {\partial }{\partial t' } = \dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t } \dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^{i'} } + \dfrac {\partial }{\partial t' } \\
\dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^{i}} = \dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial x^i} \dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^{i'} } + \dfrac {\partial t'}{\partial x^{i}} \dfrac {\partial }{\partial t'} = R^{i'}_i \dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^{i'} }
 \end{cases}  $$

Then, acting on the continuity equation, rewriting it in index notation:

$$ \dfrac {\partial \rho }{\partial t}  + \dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^i} (\rho u^i) = 0 \implies \dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial x^{i'}} + \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial t'} + R^{i'}_i \dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^{i'} } \left ( \rho u^i \right ) = 0$$

Expanding that right parcel, we have that, noting that $R_i^{i'} u^i = v^{i'} + u^{i'}$, and rearanging some terms,

$$\dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial x^{i'}} + \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial t'} + \dfrac {\partial }{\partial x^{i'} } \left ( \rho (v^{i'} + u^{i'}) \right ) = 0  \implies \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial t'} + \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial x^{i'}} u^{i'} + \dfrac {\partial u^{i'}}{\partial x^{i'}} \rho  +  \dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial x^{i'}} + v^{i'} \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial x^{i'}} = 0.$$

This can be written:

$$\dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial t'} + \dfrac {\partial}{\partial x^{i'}} (\rho u^{i'}) = - \left (\dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} + v^{i'}\right ) \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial x^{i'}}   $$

Is this last term zero? It doesn't seem like it. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ has $x$, $y$, $z$ constant, so $\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial t} = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I  figured that out today as well. The answer follows quickly, since then $\frac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} = - v^{i'}$ Please post that as an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

My deduction was indeed correct. Since $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial t} = 0$, then we get that the partial derivative of $x^{i'}$ in regards to $t$ is:

$$ \dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} = R_j ^{i'} \dfrac {\partial x^j}{\partial t} - v^{i'} = - v^{i'}.$$

It follows that:

$$\dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial t'} + \dfrac {\partial}{\partial x^{i'}} (\rho u^{i'}) = - \left (\dfrac {\partial x^{i'}}{\partial t} + v^{i'}\right ) \dfrac {\partial \rho}{\partial x^{i'}} = 0$$

The continuity equation is invariant under Galilei transformations.